# SQL Server - how can I select date-hour from a date-time field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I do the oracle equivalent of:

```
to_char(date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH')  # e.g. 2012-05-25:19
```

in SQL Server ?

I want the column for ordering which is why I want `year-month-day-hour`

Comment: for ordering? - can't you order by `date_field` itself? - assuming its a datetime that should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select convert(varchar(10),date_field,120) + ':'+
convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour,date_field))
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately mssql isn't great at custom date formats. You're stuck with string parsing:

e.g.

```
select replace(CONVERT(varchar(13),date_field,121),' ',':')
```

The full details of the formats that are available are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Note: If you're lucky enough to be in SQL 2012 you get a new `FORMAT` function, which is basically a wrapper of the .Net equivalent: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Just want to emphasise that `FORMAT` is certainly much cleaner than converting to varchar and concatenating, for those who are using 2012 and above. That part of the answer is the reason for my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server 2012** and up:

```
 SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd:HH')
```